# How do I add libmp3lame to sox?

Tags: mp3, dll, sox, lame

When I want to use sox with an mp3 I get:

```
C:\>C:\Progs\sox\sox.exe C:\Progs\tree.mp3 -C 60.2 C:\Progs\owl.mp3 tempo 1.0
C:\Progs\sox\sox.exe FAIL util: Unable to load LAME encoder library (libmp3lame).
C:\Progs\sox\sox.exe FAIL formats: can't open output file `C:\Progs\owl.mp3':
```

I downloaded libmp3lame.dll from [rarewares](http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-libraries.php) and dropped it into the sox folder but I still get the same error. What do I have to do, so that sox integrates the dll?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I downloaded the x64-Win64 version given that I have x64-Win64 but sox needs the x86-Win32 version to work correctly.